# Snowflake:PerformanceTuning:76billion Rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: To optimize the query to run faster

```
SELECT
        id,
        address,
        columns....,
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    'OrAdress', org_Adress,
    'DstAddress', dst_address
)) AS details_array,
OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    'City', CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT org_Adress:City) = 1 THEN MAX(org_Adress:City) ELSE NULL END,
    'Country', CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT org_Adress:Country) = 1 THEN MAX(org_Adress:Country) ELSE NULL END,
    'County', CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT org_Adress:County) = 1 THEN MAX(org_Adress:County) ELSE NULL END,
    'Line1', CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT org_Adress:Line1) = 1 THEN MAX(org_Adress:Line1) ELSE NULL END,
    'PostalCode', CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT org_Adress:PostalCode) = 1 THEN MAX(org_Adress:PostalCode) ELSE NULL END    ) AS single_object
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY ALL
```

I use 4XL WH and it keeps on running forever

I tried to create a temp table by identifying the bottleneck and then found that the above object_construct is what causing a lot of time, but if I remove such above object_construct, then it runs faster

I have 3 such object_constructs in the query

The requirement for the above object_construct is

To get single_address_object which has unique values in all rows Example as below data, Country and Region are common in all rows

```
    id , address
     ----------------
    111 , {   "City": "Garner",   "Country": "US",   "County": "Hancock",   "Line1": "490 W 8th St",   "PostalCode": "50438",   "Region": "TX" }
    111 , {   "City": "Colleyville",   "Country": "US",   "County": "Tarrant",   "Line1": "1002 Saddlebrook Dr",   "PostalCode": "76034",   "Region": "TX" }
    111 , {   "City": "Dublin",   "Country": "US",   "County": "Franklin",   "Line1": "545 Metro Pl S Ste 100",   "PostalCode": "43017",   "Region": "TX" }
Output
```

Need new column as below

```
 single_address_object
    ----------------------
    {"Country:"US", "Region":"TX"}
```

Is there a better way to approach it to run faster?

Comment: Try defining the clustering key on table, that will improve the performance.

Comment: i would do - 1. remove count distinct and see how much time it takes 2. Then will check data and see if line id is really unique value or we need to distinct it. And then i will ask why someone need a distinct line id.  3. See if object construct func is the issue or not.

Comment: @KoushikRoy The bottleneck looks to be the object_constructs in the query. I created a delta table with just a few hours of data and got these run times on a large warehouse:
full query - 59s
2  object_constructs - 39s
1  object_construct - 39s
no object_constructs - 16s

Comment: Given the last comment, this might be worth trying: do the sum/count across all the columns in a CTE and then sum by the required columns and the OBJECT_CONSTRUCT in the main query

Answer (score 1):

OBJECT_CONSTRUCT is slow. Defer it until after you select your columns as follows

```sql
WITH t0 as (
        SELECT
                id,
                address,
                CONCAT(IsP,'•',Id,'•',Description) AS iid
                COUNT(DISTINCT lineid) AS ln_cnt,
                SUM(ln_amt) AS ln_amt
        FROM TABLE_A
        GROUP BY ALL
)
SELECT
        id,
        address,
        object_construct(
                'IsP', split_part(iid,'•',1)::String,
                'Id', split_part(iid,'•',2)::String,
                'Description', split_part(iid,'•',3)::String
                ) AS struc,
        ln_cnt,
        ln_amt
FROM t0
```

Note that this uses character • as the delimiter. You may use whatever character will not appear in the columns in the object construction.

Comment: so basically object_construct should be at last after all SUM/MAX/Aggregrate columns right?

Comment: I would say yes. Better to construct objects over the smaller data set than over each row of data, most of which will not be returned in the query. The object was replaced above with the concatenation which is much faster and still gives the appropriate group by output.

Comment: It was working fine at first step as you mention concat but later in final when aggregrate is done like as below is running forever 
  , OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('City', CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT address:City) = 1 THEN MAX(address:City) ELSE NULL END,......

Comment: I have update the original post , the object_construct is most most expensive and running for ever

Comment: What are you doing with the resultset. If you are just viewing it/exporting it then effectively isn’t everything just a string? If so, why not create ‘struc’ using string concatenation?

Comment: needed like key:value

Comment: The query in the post now does not match the original for which a solution was provided. You need to provide the exact, complete query to execute in order to identify a better solution.

Comment: @DaveWelden Yes i have update the original post , as i see above is what exactly causing the long time .. even for 405million rows..But if i remove that object_construct its faster ... i have such 3 object_constructs

Comment: You can still construct the key:value format using string concatenation